# Maximum principle of Laplace with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a convex polygonal domain, where $\partial\Omega = \Gamma_N\cup \Gamma_D,$ with $\Gamma_N\cap\Gamma_D = \emptyset.$

Let the Laplace equation ($u\in\mathbb{P}_1(\overline{\Omega}),$ i.e., $u$ is a polynomial of degree at most one) with mixed boundary conditions, i.e.,
$$
-\Delta u  = 0 \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega  \quad u  = g \quad \text{on} \quad  \Gamma_D \quad \partial u/\partial n = 0 \quad \text{on} \quad \Gamma_N.
$$

How we can define the maximum principle? Can we say where (in which boundary) the maximum or minimum attained if $u$ is non-constant?

Comment: As long as $u$ is harmonic, the standard maximum principle holds. Your question about which boundary is interesting.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}_1(\overline{\Omega})$? Did you know Hopf lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_lemma?

Comment: @thing It means that $u$ is a polynomial of degree at most one. Yes, I know Hopf Lemma, but how can we apply it on polygonal domain (for example a square domain)?

Comment: On the smooth part of the boundary, where the normal derivative vanishes, there cannot be a maximum or a minimum. That is, maximum and minimum are possible only at corner points and on smooth parts where Dirichlet conditions are specified. Although, I don't understand what is specific about the polynomial case.

Comment: @thing Is any reference for that $u$ cannot have the maximum or minimum where the normal derivative vanishes? I am interested only on convex polygonal domains.  In fact, the polynomial degree is irrespective (I have a polynomial of degree at most one so then I get that u is harmonic).

Comment: By a polynomial of degree at most $1$ you mean a polynomial of the form $ax+by+c$ or of the form $axy+bx+cy+d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By polynomial of degree one, I assume you mean $ax+by+c$. Then your function is convex. There is a maximum principle for convex functions that says that a continuous convex function defined on a compact convex set attains its maximum at an extreme point.

[Bauer's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer_maximum_principle#:%7E:text=Bauer%27s%20maximum%20principle%20is%20the,the%20German%20mathematician%20Heinz%20Bauer.)
By a rotation and a translation, you can assume that this extreme point is the origin and that the segment with endpoints $(0,0)$ and $(d,0)$ with $d$ positive is one of the sides of your polygon. Then the normal is in the vertical direction. If in that segment you have  a nontrivial portion of $\Gamma_N$, you get $b=0$ (note that after the rotation and translation, the constants $a$ $b$ and $c$ changed), so your function is $ax+c$. To have a maximum at $0$ you need $a<0$, since your function is not constant. So you can have a maximum in the portion $\Gamma_N$.

PS. Even without using the maximum principle, if you have the Neumann condition on one side of your polygon, you can rotate and translate it and, by the previous reasoning, you have that your function is a function of one variable, which trivializes the problem. By polygonal domain, do you allow the boundary to be curved? That would change things